# How to open this electric plug?

Tags: electrical

Not sure if it's the right place to ask, and I must be missing something really simple.
Anyway, I'm trying to open this electric plug. Normally you just need to unscrew the screw and thats all, but on this one the screw seems to do nothing!!

Here are a few images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any idea?
Cheers!

Comment: Try twisting the wider end.

Comment: Thanks! For this one the twisting was crucial!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the screw completely.
Then the (usually) rubber enclosure slides off the hard plastic interior.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have 2. For one of them just needed to remove completely the screw. For the other (not in the pictures) it also needed a few pushes and twists.